# How to add a new model in laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have added a new model called Complaints.php  but its not working.

`$users = DB::table('complaints')->get();
return $users;`

from the above code Iam able to get the response

But If I use the below code not getting error

`$users = Compliant::all();
return $users;`

**Complaints.php**

```
    <?php use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait; use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface; 

class Complaint extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

 use UserTrait, RemindableTrait; 

protected $table = 'complaints';
 public $timestamps = false; 

function static function uploadComplaint($data){ 
return $data; 
} 
}
```

Comment: What code have you put inside `Complaints.php`?

Comment: Your controller (Complaints.php) extends of BaseController?

Comment: `<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
class Complaints extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
 use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
 protected $table = 'complaints';
 public $timestamps = false;
  function static function uploadComplaint($data){
    return $data;
  }
 }
?>`

Comment: Try with BaseController.

Comment: You have a spelling error. See my answer.

Comment: Tip: use an artisan extension to generate your models, controllers etc: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

Comment: Also, get into the habit of naming your models by the common singular-convention; the model only represents a single complaint, whereas - if you have multiple complaints - you'll get a `Collection` consisting of `Complaint`-objects; which is why you'd name your class/model `Complaint`  instead of `Complaints`.

Comment: I have done as you said but still its not working

Comment: Where is your model file placed?

Comment: Did you correct the spelling error?

Answer (score 1):

You have a **spelling error**.

`class Complaint`

Hence, the code should be:

```
$users = Complaint::all();
return $users
```

So `Compliant` is not the same as `Complaint`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got an answer in model I added public class I removed public and it works fine thanks to all.